# Any optimize way to iterate excel and provide data into pd.read_sql() as a string one by one

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

[image: I have to read this excel and get the Report2 queries, B2 (cell) and C2 (cell) and compare the resultset then Report3 queries B3 and C3 and again compare and so on ...]

```
#here I have to apply the loop which can provide me the queries from excel for respective reports:
    df1 = pd.read_sql(SQLqueryB2, con=con1)
    df2 = pd.read_sql(ORCqueryC2, con=con2)
    if (df1.equals(df2)):
        print(Report2 +" : is Pass")
```

Can we achieve above by something doing like this (by iterating ndarray)
`df = pd.read_excel(path) for col, item in df.iteritems():`
OR do the only option left to read the excel from "openpyxl" library and iterate row, columns and then provide the values. Hope I am clear with the question, if any doubt please comment me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to loop through an excel file, run the 2 queries, see if they match and output the result, correct?

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# add user, pass, database name
con = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{USER}:{PWD}@{HOST}/{DB}")
file = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx')

file['Result'] = ''  # placeholder
for i, row in file.iterrows():
    df1 = pd.read_sql(row['SQLQuery'], con)
    df2 = pd.read_sql(row['Oracle Queries'], con)
    file.loc[i, 'Result'] = 'Pass' if df1.equals(df2) else 'Fail'

file.to_excel('results.xlsx', index=False)
```

This will save a file named results.xlsx that mirrors the original data but adds a column named Result that will be Pass or Fail.

Example results.xlsx:

[image]

Comment: Hi @mr_mooo_cow, one extra column gets added in the results.xlsx name is "unnamed" and contains value (0,1,2,3 ...) and this gets added at very first column place. I think those are index values. Can we make that column addition in the Result sheet as 'False'

Comment: file.to_excel('results.xlsx', index=False). I've updated the answer.

Comment: To be honest, doing this with Pandas looks like using a sledgehammer to crack a walnut.